# QTableWidget Resize with Dialogue Python QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am developing python qgis plugin with QTableWidget inside a tabWidget. How can i set my QTableWidget size and QTabwidget with the Dialogue box. So that when someone expand the dialogue box of the plugin from QGIS window,it won't show a small window of the Attribute table. First image is showing original window.But after changing dialogue size it becomes like second image

[image]

second image:[image]

Comment: Please fix image url

Comment: One good habit, it's to use right click on your container (the window, tabwidget ...) and to use always a vertical layout.

Comment: This is a question for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/).